# Unable to search message with message-ID, BAD [b'Could not parse command']

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, gmail, imaplib

Good day everyone,
I'm working on a personal python small project here, trying to search messages with messages-id, but encounter error as below :

```
imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']
```

this is a sample of the code :

```
line = '<ABCDefghIJKlmnOpqRS@mail.gmail.com>'
typ, data = mail.search(None, '(HEADER Message-ID "%s")' % line)
```

Comment: I think you should take out the `(` and `)` in the command and the `<` and `>` in the email address.

Comment: There's a question for getting a message from the Message-ID here, is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775667

Comment: () are not needed unless you need to group search terms.  I would try to remove those first.  Also turn on imaplib debugging to make sure you are sending what you expect.  Also: what server are you connecting to?  Some niche servers have terrible `SEARCH` implementations.